# Can't partition my hard drive for Ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive

I installed Ubuntu just yesterday, but I had to install it to just 6GB the OS taking up around 3GB I think, but I have about 260GB free on my one and only hard drive. How can I utilize that space for Ubuntu?

I have it set to dual boot, my other OS being Windows. I've managed to split 50GB off of that, and it comes up as "unallocated space", but when I try to either create "a new simple volume" from that it tells me that the drive already has the maximum number of partitions on it.

When I try to Extend the 6GB partition Ubuntu is on now, the option is grayed out (I'm doing this via Control Panel on Windows under Disk Management or create and format drive partitions or something like that).

On Ubuntu, the 50GBs comes up as "unusable space". I also can't delete any partitions, other than extend the 50GB one back to the original Windows OS partition, another is a recovery partition, and there's 2 more of about 100MB each.

I want Ubuntu really bad, and if I can't fix this I'm going to have to buy an external hard drive. I'm running Ubuntu 13.10, 64-bit, Core i3, etc.

Comment: It's a little late for me, so I won't post an answer, but don't try to do this in Windows. Windows doesn't understand Ubuntu, so it might break things for you. Ubuntu is able to do all of it however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have free space then skip to step2

step1: shrink the Windows volume from Windows Disk Management in Adminstrative Tools. That will give you free space.(don't use Gparted)

step2:

- Downoad GParted Live, [here](http://cdn.mirror.garr.it/sf/project/gparted/gparted-live-stable/0.17.0-4/gparted-live-0.17.0-4-i486.iso)
- Burn it to a CD and boot from it, then use the freed disk space after shrinking Windows drive (or if you have free initialy) to resize Ubuntu drive.

Comment: Ok, step one is easy enough, as for step two, like I said, I'm new at this, by burn it to a CD do you simply mean to burn the files to a CD or write it to a CD in the same way that I wrote Ubuntu to my flash drive and if so what program should I use? Thanks for the help!

Comment: The downloaded is an iso file then burn this iso to a CD using a burning tool so taht it run as live cd and yes same as you do with ubuntu iso and then reboot and change tp boot from cd from ur bios and then just read and you will know how to do

Comment: And what if the download keeps stopping randomly? I know it's not finished because the file will only be like 35MBs or something.. I got to 70 once, but it will just stop as if it's done as a complete file and all, but obviously it's not do you have another link to download it or something?

Comment: I finally got it. There was something wrong with your link I navigated to it indirectly and the download work and I have it fixed now. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @blenderking You are welcome my friend. Glad for you